# Extracting lowest numeric value from multiple certain values within a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have multiple comma separated values within one cell, e.g.,

K3 = US 35516109 A 20090116,US 35142006 A 20060210,US 1154108 P 20080117

Is there is a way to extract the lowest value out of all of the numeric values that are to the right of every instance of text A and text P?

In the above example, 20060210 should be extracted because it is the lowest value of 20090116 (which is to the right of A), 20060210 (to the right of A), and 20080117 (to the right of P).

Comment: Are all of the numeric values 8 digits?

Comment: All of the values to the right of A and P that are to be compared are all 8 digits; the ones to the left are not all 8 digits and some are not all numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple regex function.

```
Option Explicit

Function lowestNumber(str As String) As Variant
    Dim n As Long, nums() As Variant
    Static rgx As Object, cmat As Object

    Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    lowestNumber = CVErr(xlErrNA)

    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "[AP] [0-9]{8}"
        If .Test(str) Then
            lowestNumber = 1E+99
            Set cmat = .Execute(str)
            For n = 0 To cmat.Count - 1
                lowestNumber = Application.Min(lowestNumber, Val(Mid(cmat.Item(n), 3)))
            Next n
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

If this does fit every circumstance then I'm sure the pattern can be modified to suit other situations.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Double Split 2.0

This function ignores **A** or **P**, it just extracts the minimum of the values of the last string in each (comma) separated string.

### The Code

```
Function MinDate(CellRange As Range) As Long

    Const strDel1 As String = ","   ' 1st Split Delimiter
    Const strDel2 As String = " "   ' 2nd Split Delimiter

    Dim vntS1 As Variant  ' 1st Split Array
    Dim vntS2 As Variant  ' 2nd Split Array
    Dim vntT As Variant   ' Target Array
    Dim i As Long         ' Array Row Counter

    On Error GoTo ProcedureExit

    ' Split the cell value by 1st Split Delimiter into 1st Split Array.
    vntS1 = Split(CellRange, strDel1)
    ' Resize Target Array to size of 1st Split Array.
    ReDim vntT(UBound(vntS1))
    ' Loop through elements of 1st Split Array.
    For i = 0 To UBound(vntS1)
        ' Split 1st Split Array by 2nd Split Delimiter into 2nd Split Array.
        vntS2 = Split(vntS1(i), strDel2)
        ' Add the last element of 2nd Split Array to Target Array.
        vntT(i) = Val(vntS2(UBound(vntS2)))
    Next

    ' Check for the minimum.
    MinDate = vntT(0)
    For i = 1 To UBound(vntT)
        If vntT(i) < vntT(i - 1) Then
            MinDate = vntT(i)
        End If
    Next

ProcedureExit:

End Function
```

### Usage in Excel

```
=MinDate(K3)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this function, but it's returning a "0" value for every cell, with the warning "The formula in this cell differs from the formulas in this area of the spreadsheet".

Comment: @J.H.: If the cell is empty or isn't of the type you are referring in you question, it will return 0. If you have data of the type you mentioned in e.g. **A1** you have to use **=MinDate(A1)**. The warning message refers to the fact that you have different formulas below or above. Show me an example of data where it shows 0.

Comment: Here is a sample cell that the function is returning a 0: A2 = US 57551890 A 19900830,US 40210489 A 19890901,US 24209688 A 19880908,US 3811087 A 19870414,US 3615487 A 19870403,US 85356986 A 19860418.  I am using =MinDate(A2)

Comment: I've changed **vntS1 = Split(CellRange, ",")** to **vntS1 = Split(CellRange, strDel1)** and I've uncommented the **On Error ...** line. Sorry once again. It's not my day.